# RabbitMQ reconnect logic is not working on abrupt restart of RabbitMQ server

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, node-amqplib

My node application and [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com) server are running on [docker](https://www.docker.com/).
That nodejs application have reconnect logic which works great when I gracefully restart RabbitMQ service by `kill` command in RabbitMQ container or by `sudo docker-compose restart -t 10 rabbitmq` which wait till 10 seconds before sending forcefull `kill` singal to RabbitMQ service.

But when I forcefully restart RabbitMQ service by `sudo docker-compose restart -t 0 rabbitmq` then reconnect logic does not work. `lsof` command on nodejs app container does not show any connections.

```
var amqp = require('amqplib')
var appRoot = require('app-root-path')
var rabbitMQConfig = require(`${appRoot}/config`).rabbitmq
var winston = require(`${appRoot}/logger`)
var utils = require(`${appRoot}/utils`)
var util = require('util')
var rabbitMQController = require(`${appRoot}/controllers/rabbitMQController`)
var request = require('request-promise')

function getRabbitMQConnectionString(rabbitMQConfig) {
    var connPrefix = rabbitMQConfig.prefix
    if (rabbitMQConfig.authEnabled === true) {
        var credentials = rabbitMQConfig.userName + ":" + rabbitMQConfig.password +"@"
        connPrefix += credentials
        connString = util.format(connPrefix +'%s:%s%s', rabbitMQConfig.host, rabbitMQConfig.port, rabbitMQConfig.vhost)
    } else {
        connString = util.format(connPrefix +'%s:%s%s', rabbitMQConfig.host, rabbitMQConfig.port, rabbitMQConfig.vhost)
    }
    return connString   
}

var connString = getRabbitMQConnectionString(rabbitMQConfig)

var initializeRabbitMQ = async function(channel) {
    await channel.assertExchange(rabbitMQConfig.exchange, 'direct', { durable: true })
    await channel.assertQueue(rabbitMQConfig.queue, { durable: true })
    var url = util.format('%s%s:%s/api/bindings/%s/e/%s/q/%s', rabbitMQConfig.httpPrefix, rabbitMQConfig.host, rabbitMQConfig.managementPort, encodeURIComponent(rabbitMQConfig.vhost), rabbitMQConfig.exchange, rabbitMQConfig.queue) 
    var options = {
        "method": "GET",
        "uri": url,
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + new Buffer(rabbitMQConfig.userName + ":" + rabbitMQConfig.password).toString("base64"),
        },
        'json': true,
        'timeout': 15000
    }
    var result = await request(options)
    // console.log('alok', result)
    result.forEach(async function(item) {
        await channel.unbindQueue(rabbitMQConfig.queue, rabbitMQConfig.exchange, item.routing_key)
    })
    rabbitMQConfig.source.forEach(async function(item) {
        await channel.bindQueue(rabbitMQConfig.queue, rabbitMQConfig.exchange, item)
    })
}

var connect = async function() {
    var conn = await amqp.connect(connString)
    var channel =  await conn.createChannel()
    await initializeRabbitMQ(channel)
    rabbitMQController.processMessages()
    return channel
}

var prepareExports = async function(exportsObj) {
    try {
        exportsObj["connection"] = connect()
        var channel = await exportsObj["connection"]
        channel.on('error', function(error) {
            winston.error(utils.getLogString("rabbitmq_channel_error", "", "", error.stack))
        })
        channel.on('close', function() {
            winston.error(utils.getLogString("rabbitmq_channel_close", "", "", ""))
            prepareExports(exportsObj)
        })
    } catch (error) {
        winston.error(utils.getLogString(arguments.callee.name, "", "", error.stack))
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(resolve, 5000)
        })
        prepareExports(exportsObj)
    }
}

prepareExports(module.exports)
```

What should be proper way to make it work even in case of forceful abrupt restart of RabbitMQ service?

Comment: I could be missing something, but I don't see any reconnect logic in this code.

Comment: @shkaper: see last line of code `prepareExports(module.exports)`

Comment: Right, I didn't pay attention to that.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of tests with a local instance of RabbitMQ showed that a `connection.on('close')` listener is always being fired when RabbitMQ restarts, so I suggest you try a Connection listener instead of Channel.

While it's true that the library will emit `close` events for all Channels on a closed Connection, there is no reason to *only* listen to Channel events (as opposed to Connection events). Moreover, a couple of benefits of listening to Connection events:

1. If a Channel emits `error` and there is no corresponding listener, the error will propagate to an underlying Connection.
2. If a Connection emits `close`, the listener is called with a reason in the error message. The Connection emits `close` events for all its Channels *without* specifying a reason.

Answer (score 1):

On error in connection there should be error in chennel also which is not getting raise, its a bug in [amqplib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib). So fix is to register a function on error in connection.

```
var connect = async function() {
    var conn = await amqp.connect(connString)
    var channel =  await conn.createChannel()
    await initializeRabbitMQ(channel)
    conn.on('error', () => {}) // this is solving problem
    return channel
}

var prepareExports = async function(exportsObj) {
    try {
        exportsObj["connection"] = connect()
        var channel = await exportsObj["connection"]
        channel.on('error', function(error) {
            winston.error(utils.getLogString("rabbitmq_channel_error", "", "", error.stack))
        })
        channel.on('close', function() {
            winston.error(utils.getLogString("rabbitmq_channel_close", "", "", ""))
            prepareExports(exportsObj)
        })
    } catch (error) {
        winston.error(utils.getLogString(arguments.callee.name, "", "", error.stack))
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(resolve, 5000)
        })
        prepareExports(exportsObj)
    }
}

prepareExports(module.exports)
rabbitMQController.processMessages()
```

Answer (score 0):

`connection.close()` is available in official api at http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#model_close

In addition to listening to channel we have to listen to connection also.

```
var connect = async function() {
    var conn = await amqp.connect(connString)
    var channel =  await conn.createChannel()
    channel.conn_ = conn
    await initializeRabbitMQ(channel)
    // rabbitMQController.processMessages()
    return channel
}

var prepareExports = async function(exportsObj) {
    try {
        exportsObj["connection"] = connect()
        var channel = await exportsObj["connection"]
        var conn = channel.conn_
        channel.on('error', function(error) {
            winston.error(utils.getLogString("rabbitmq_channel_error", "", "", error.stack))
        })
        channel.on('close', function() {
            winston.error(utils.getLogString("rabbitmq_channel_close", "", "", ""))
            prepareExports(exportsObj)
        })
        conn.on('error', function(error) {
            winston.error(utils.getLogString("rabbitmq_conn_error", "", "", error.stack))
        })
        conn.on('close', function() {
            winston.error(utils.getLogString("rabbitmq_conn_close", "", "", ""))
            prepareExports(exportsObj)
        })
    } catch (error) {
        winston.error(utils.getLogString(arguments.callee.name, "", "", error.stack))
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(resolve, 5000)
        })
        prepareExports(exportsObj)
    }
}

prepareExports(module.exports)
rabbitMQController.processMessages()
```